# Accessing a master page public variable from user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, public

```
public partial class MasterPages_Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public LoggedInUser ThisUser;
```

This is in my master page, and my user control is running on the page.  In my user control however, I can't seem to reference `ThisUser`, do I *have* to pass it in to the control as a parameter?  Is there any way to directly reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely!  Take a look at the methods and properties of an asp.net page.  I've done similiar using:

```
HtmlForm mainform = (HtmlForm)Master.FindControl("form1");
```

Where the important part is the Master.FindControl();

This is a part of the Page class.  Page.Master will get you to the master page of the current page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that there's *some* way to avoid passing an instance of `LoggedInUser` to your control, however it's probably best to pass it as a parameter as doing so promotes reuse of the control because it will be more loosely coupled.